Initialize secondary datasource based on JobParameter at runtime / lazily
I'm working on a Spring Batch app where I have a batch data source configured during context startup (as standard) and I want to have a secondary data source that must be initialized based on a job parameter called "country".
I have secondary data source properties configured for each country:
#LTU
country.instances.ltu.url=...
country.instances.ltu.username=...
country.instances.ltu.password=...
country.instances.ltu.driver-class-name=...
#ITA
country.instances.ita.url=...
country.instances.ita.username=...
country.instances.ita.password=...
country.instances.ita.driver-class-name=...
#FRA
country.instances.fra.url=...
country.instances.fra.username=...
country.instances.fra.password=...
country.instances.fra.driver-class-name=...
... and so on

I have a class @Configuration for data sources:
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

  @Autowired
  private CountryProperties countryProperties; // @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "country")

  // Batch Datasource configurations ...

  @Bean
  @JobScope
  public DataSource secondaryDataSource(
      @Value("#{jobParameters['country']}") String instanceName
  ) {
    InstanceProperties instanceProperties = countryProperties.getInstances()
        .get(instanceName);
    Assert.notNull(instanceProperties, "instance configuration is required");
    DataSourceBuilder<?> dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create()
        .driverClassName(instanceProperties.getDriverClassName())
        .url(instanceProperties.getUrl())
        .username(instanceProperties.getUsername())
        .password(instanceProperties.getPassword());

    return dataSourceBuilder.build();
  }

  @Bean
  public DataSourceTransactionManager secondaryTransactionManager() {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(secondaryDataSource(null));
  }
}

And I have another @Configuration for Job that autowires the data source / transaction manager:
@Configuration
public class TestJob {

  @Autowired
  protected JobRepository jobRepository;

  @Autowired
  protected JobLauncher jobLauncher;

  @Autowired
  protected DataSource secondaryDataSource;

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("secondaryTransactionManager")
  protected PlatformTransactionManager secondaryTransactionManager;

  @Bean
  public Job job() {
    return new JobBuilder("testJob", jobRepository)
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .start(step())
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    simpleAsyncTaskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("thread-n");
    return simpleAsyncTaskExecutor;
  }

  @Bean
  public ColumnRangePartitioner columnRangePartitioner() {
    ColumnRangePartitioner columnRangePartitioner = new ColumnRangePartitioner();
    columnRangePartitioner.setDataSource(secondaryDataSource);
    columnRangePartitioner.setTable("GLB_STORAGE_DOCUMENTS");
    return columnRangePartitioner;
  }

  @Bean
  public Step step() {
    return new StepBuilder("saveDataToCSVStep", jobRepository)
        .partitioner(slaveStep().getName(), columnRangePartitioner())
        .step(slaveStep())
        .gridSize(2)
        .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public Step slaveStep() {
    return new StepBuilder("step", jobRepository)
        .<StorageDocument, StorageDocument>chunk(100, secondaryTransactionManager)
        .reader(itemReader())
        .writer(itemWriter())
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public JdbcCursorItemReader<StorageDocument> itemReader() {
    return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<StorageDocument>()
        .dataSource(secondaryDataSource)
        .name("reader")
        .sql("select STORAGE_DOCUMENT_ID from GLB_STORAGE_DOCUMENTS")
        .rowMapper(new StorageDocumentRowMapper())
        .build();

  }

  @Bean
  public FlatFileItemWriter<StorageDocument> itemWriter() {
    BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<StorageDocument> fieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
    fieldExtractor.setNames(
        new String[]{"storageDocumentId"});
    DelimitedLineAggregator<StorageDocument> lineAggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<>();
    lineAggregator.setDelimiter(",");
    lineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(fieldExtractor);
    return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<StorageDocument>()
        .name("flatFileItemWriter")
        .resource(new FileSystemResource("target/test.csv"))
        .headerCallback(writer -> writer.write("STORAGEDOCUMENTID"))
        .lineAggregator(lineAggregator)
        .build();
  }
}

When I run the batch I get this error:
2024-04-15T12:47:28,823 ERROR [thread-n1] o.s.b.c.s.AbstractStep:
Encountered an error executing step step in job testJob
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to
initialize the reader
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:155)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:124)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:292)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:226)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.lambda$createTask$0(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:132)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ScopeNotActiveException:
Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.secondaryDataSource':
Scope 'job' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a
scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:200)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy61.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractCursorItemReader.initializeConnection(AbstractCursorItemReader.java:450)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractCursorItemReader.doOpen(AbstractCursorItemReader.java:430)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:152)
    ... 7 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for job scope
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.JobScope.getContext(JobScope.java:157)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.JobScope.get(JobScope.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:361)
    ... 14 more

From what I've found around, I seem to have run into this "problem":

There are some practical limitations of using job-scoped beans in
multi-threaded or partitioned steps. Spring Batch does not control the
threads spawned in these use cases, so it is not possible to set them
up correctly to use such beans. Hence, it is not recommended to use
job-scoped beans in multi-threaded or partitioned steps.

How do I get out of this situation since it is not recommended to use JobScope in a multi-threaded step?
How can I configure a data source using JobParameters at runtime / lazily in Spring Batch?
P.S. I'm open to suggestions to change the "design" of my batch to achieve what is required.

I had a similar problem with having to set up a datasource dynamically during runtime,  and this helped me.
